# Why is a symmetric group a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

If the identity axiom for groups is the following $ae = ea = a$ ($e$ the identity element) and the operation for a symmetric group is function composition then how does a symmetric group pass this test?

Specifically suppose that we have two bijections of set $S = \{1,2,3\}$, $a = (2,1,3)$ and identity $e=(1,2,3)$, then the identity axiom is only working for function composition when the identity is the *left* function ($ea \ne ae$).

Can anyone explain if I understand this correctly?

Comment: Think about the identity function.

Comment: Could you provide the result of $ea$ and $ae$ then?

Comment: You obviously have not understood it correctly, since the symmetric group is indeed a group.  You'll have to put in the details of your calculations before we can point out exactly what you are misunderstanding.

Comment: Are you using cycle notation, or are you using abbreviated 2-line notation? That is, does "$(2,1,3)$" represent the permutation that sends $2\mapsto 1\mapsto3\mapsto 2$, or does it represent the second line of the 2-line notation $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&3\\2&1&3\end{array}\right)$, which is the map sending $1\mapsto 2$, $2\mapsto 1$ and $3\mapsto 3$?

Comment: If the subgroup generated by $a$ and $e$ has only two elements, it's commutative

Comment: @ArturoMagidin notation is the second one you have shown, I am not familiar with cycle notation.

Comment: @MichaelMunta: that explains some of the comments. You will find that most mathematicians use cycle notation instead of 2-line or abbreviated 2-line notation, so most people reading your post (mis)understood what you meant when you wrote "$(1,2,3)$". For example, 5xun's answer below that says "$(1,2,3)$ is not the identity" says that because of the notation clash. **Note well:** your notation is not "incorrect", it's just not the *usual* way that we write permutations (it is also not unheard of...)

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer:*

$(1,2,3)$ is not the identity. The identity element of the symmetric group maps each $x$ to itself.

*Slightly longer answer*:

Following a variation of logic, we can easily prove that $\mathbb R$ is *not* a group for addition. For example, take two elements of $\mathbb R$, $a=10$ and identity $e=498123921$. Then the identity axiom is not working, because $a+e\neq a$.

*Longer answer*:

The mistake you made is that you did not correctly and completely write out the identity axiom for groups.

In particular, the axioms states the following:

> If $G$ is a group, then there exists some $e\in G$ such that for every $a\in G$, we have $ae=ea=a$.

The axiom does not claim that you can **choose** what the identity of the group is. It states that the identity of a group is an element that must satisfy a particular condition.

It is fairly easy to show that the permutation $e$ for which $e(1)=1, e(2)=2$ and $e(3)=3$ satisfies the condition and is therefore the identity of $S_3$.

Comment: I guess the OP is using the notation $(\pi(1),\pi(2),\pi(3))$. In this notation, $(1,2,3)$ is the identity.

Comment: @lhf To me, $(1,2,3)$ looks like a cycle.

Comment: It seems I have used incorrect notation. What I meant is the first comment on your answer.

Comment: @MichaelMunta In that case, $ae=ea=a$ is true. You can see that $ea(1)=e(a(1))=e(2)=2, ea(2)=e(a(2))=e(1)=1, ea(3)=e(a(3))=e(3)=3$, meaning that $ea=a$. Similarly, $ae(1)=a(e(1))=a(1)=2, ae(2)=a(e(2))=a(2)=1, ae(3)=a(e(3))=a(3)=3$ means that $ae=e$.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $e = (1,2,3)$ to mean the function that maps $(1,2,3)$ to $(1,2,3)$ and $a = (2,1,3)$ to mean the function that maps $(1,2,3)$ to $(2,1,3)$, then it is certainly true that $ae = ea = a$. Just try it on each element. $ae$ maps $(1,2,3) \rightarrow (1,2,3) \rightarrow (2,1,3)$ and $ea$ maps $(1,2,3)\rightarrow (2,1,3)\rightarrow (2,1,3)$.

If you are instead using cycle notation, then the identity element is *not* $e = (1\;2\;3)$, but $e = (1)(2)(3)$. The same argument as the previous paragraph shows this is the identity element.

Answer (score 0):

With the notation you appear to be using, this is what happens:-

**If you do $a$ then $e$**

1 goes to 2 then to 2

2 goes to 1 then to 1

3 goes to 3 then to 3

**If you do $e$ then $a$**

1 goes to 1 then to 2

2 goes to 2 then to 1

3 goes to 3 then to 3

I hope that helps you to clarify your thoughts.